# Change default browser in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am using "01_hello" in RStudio and while it won't show the histogram when the program opens by default in IE, even in Chrome, the slider bar does not work. I cannot slide the bar and see the change in the histogram.

How can I change the default browser in R so that the shiny launches Chrome and not IE.?

Comment: Are you needing to keep IE as your default browser on your machine or can you make Chrome your default browser?

Comment: Ideally id like to keep IE as a default browser since its a work computer and their applications support only IE. In chrome, I face an additional issue of the slider bars for applications that may have one not working

Comment: I use Firefox on my work computer (despite everyone insisting our products are only compatible with IE) so my suggestion for a quick fix is to use that as your default browser for your machine. You shouldn't have any problems with Shiny at all. In the meantime I will hunt for your desired solution.

Answer (score 2):

On the main site this issue has been asked in the comments, the moderators have said that it will open your machine's default browser -- it does not rely on R env variables.

Source: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that is what I've been doing. Anyway, even if I were to ignore the browser issue. I'm having troubles using slider buttons in Chrome. This issue doesnt happen in IE, but in IE histograms that go with the slider don't show up. So while Chrome displays everything, the reactive element (the slider) don't change/cannot be changed.

Comment: The only reason I've heard of that happening is because your corporate firewall could be explicitly blocking websockets connections, though I don't know how to test that theory without asking your IT department. Can you also verify that you have Chrome, R and `shinyapps` updated to the most current versions? Also, make sure you have IE version 10+ as previous versions are not supported by `shinyapps`.

Comment: Sigh, wish I had a better solution. Our corporate IT does not allow us to change from IE 11 as the default browser, but we have Chrome...