# Automatically open R Shiny App in Chrome Web Browser only while Internet Explorer is the default browser

Tags: r, google-chrome, internet-explorer, shiny

How to automatically open an R Shiny app only in the Chrome Web Browser, while Internet Explorer is the default browser?

Example of a run.r file:

```
require(shiny)
folder_address = 'C:/Temp/Test/'
runApp(folder_address,launch.browser=TRUE)
```

which is called by a .bat file:

```
START /MIN "" "R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Temp\Test\run.r"
```

I want to use runApp() and not open it through RStudio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default browser in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129215/change-default-browser-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

I added the following line to .Rprofile, which is located in C:\Users\username\Documents:

options(browser="C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")

Notice however that an R Shiny app launched in RStudio still opens in the default browser. In my case IE.